# saving a picture from online to local storage qt 5.1

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qtnetwork, qfile

I'm writing a program which will have a list of users and each one will have their own picture from an online source.
I am downloading the data successfully and I'm struggling with formatting the picture format.
It saves the file successfully but it doesn't save it in a readable format.

```
void FriendsListProcess::picRequesFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
        return;
    }
    emit savePic(pic_name_path,data);
    reply->deleteLater();
}

void FriendsListProcess::savePicToFile(QString file, QByteArray &pic_data)
{
qDebug() << "File name from write pic: " << file;
QFile f(file);
if(f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    QDataStream out(&f);
    out << pic_data;
        f.close();
}
}
```

when i try to open the saved file windows says

```
"Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format. or you don't have the lates updates to Photo Viewer"
```

have you guys got any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a correct image on the remote host, i.e. does it work after downloading with your browser or wget, etc? OT: your save method lacks the error check for open, as well as for the write.

Comment: yeah i can click onto the link that i print out to my debug console and it downloads no problem with any broswer

Comment: Why do you not use QDataStream for binary data like this? An image is not a text stream. Btw, your code wastes a lot of memory if the image is big by not reading by chunks. Is the write operation successful? Please check that.

Comment: i just tried that and i get the same result

Comment: You _cannot_ get the same result since you have something printed out for the error check...

Comment: ok sorry i misunderstood your answer. Im guessing that is probably my problem. it's probably not writing the whole image so i still get an error when trying to open it. so how would you suggest i write the above code to make it more efficient?

Comment: i also changed the above code to :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following issues in your code:

- You write the image data as if it was a text stream, whereas it is a binary stream.
- You reading everything in without reading by chunks. This potentially wastes more memory than necessary.
- You lack the error checking in your code.
- You needlessly have the signal/slot indirection in here.
- It is superfluous to check the QNetworkReply error in the finished handler slot because such things would be better caught in the error signal handler slot.
- You open the file as `ReadOnly`, whereas you would like to *write* it.
- You open the file with text open mode flag, whereas an image is binary data.

I would be writing something like this:

```
void FriendsListProcess::picRequesFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QFile file(pic_name_path);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open the file for reading:" << file.fileName();
        return;
    }

    // You would need to make sure you do not get irrelevant data in the meantime
    while (reply->bytesAvailable()) {
        if (file.write(reply->read(512)) == -1)
            qDebug() << "Error while reading data:" << file.errorString();
    }
}
```

Comment: i really am sorry. with qt i really am an amateur when it comes to dealing with file and many aspects. so please may i ask how i would loop the above code?

Comment: oh sorry. i didn't reload the page

Comment: thank you so much man. people like you really help people like me out sooooooo much. your a life saver  thank you